# Can stopped process have running threads?

Tags: linux, unix

If I want to know if some multithreaded process is stopped and all it's threads are stopped, can I examine only `/proc/pid/status` for `T` flag in `State` field or should I look at every `/proc/pid/task/thread_id/status` and check if it's stopped?

Comment: All threads are stopped. Just check process flags